# ReactJS - Responsive virtual masonry of selectable and draggable images

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, masonry, react-virtualized

I am trying to build the responsive masonry grid of images, and I would like to be able to perform multiselect (with cursor+shift) and rearrange images by being able to drag and drop  them.

Is there any library, which provides such or similar functionality?

Maybe I am missed  one, while investigating. There are great standalone packages, for the standalone problems, like masonry, or drag'n'drop, but it's not very clear if it's possible to combine them.

Here is an example, of me trying to integrate masonry with dnd library - [codesandox](https://codesandbox.io/s/masonic-example-forked-z4t2t?file=/src/index.js).
Please, could somebody help me, if there is already library which solves this case, or point me, what I am missing at my sample of combining existing ones?

Comment: Gridstack.js might be able to do what you want.

Comment: @altho, thanks, it looks promising, but I wasn't able to found that it supports virtual lists,  is it?

Comment: I don't know about that. You might want to ask them directly or implement virtualized lists from scratch

Comment: react-grid-gallery might be an option

Comment: You might also check out a canvas-based solution?

Comment: @ANimator120 the `react-grid-gallery` looks good from UI perspective, but it doesn't support virtual lists, select with "shift", drag&drop out of the box, and integrate other  libraries for this goal is tedious and not working  as expected.